# Ansible check if variables are set

Tags: ansible

I want to automate the installation process of our software for our client. Therefore I wrote an Ansible playbook which has a task which should check if all the mandatory variables are set:

```
- name: Check environment variables.
  hosts: all
  vars_files: 
    - required_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - fail: msg="Variable '{{ item }}' is not defined"
      when: item not in hostvars[inventory_hostname]
      with_items: 
        - required_vars
```

The `required_vars.yml` looks like this:

```
required_vars:
  - APPHOME: /home/foo/bar
  - TMPDIR: /home/foo/bar/tmp
```

When I execute the playbook via `ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev.yml playbook.yml` I get the following error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost]

TASK [fail] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************failed: 
[localhost] (item=required_vars) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "required_vars", "msg": "Variable 'required_vars' is not defined"}
```

It is obvious that I am doing something wrong, but I cannot point to the error. Can you help me please?

**Edit**: the accepted answer helped me out. Thank you.
But I have two more questions:

1. The executed task says:

   ```
   TASK [fail]
   skipping: [some_ip] => (item=/root)
   skipping: [some_ip] => (item=TMPDIR: /home/foo/bar/tmp)
   ```

It is getting skipped because all variables are set, correct?

2. I think I figured out how to print the correct message, if the variable is not set:

   ```
   - name: Check environment variables.
     hosts: all
     vars_files: 
       - required_vars.yml
     tasks:
       - fail: 
           msg: "Variable '{{ item }}' is not defined"
         with_items: "{{ required_vars }}"
         when: item is undefined
   ```

Correct? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You want to iterate over the value of `required_vars` variable value, so you need to provide it as an argument to `with_items: "{{ required_vars }}"`:

   ```
   with_items: "{{ required_vars }}"
   ```

   Currently you are providing a list of a single element with a statically defined string `required_vars`.
2. You need to change the data type of the elements in your `required_vars` list to strings:

   ```
   required_vars:
     - "APPHOME: /home/foo/bar"
     - "TMPDIR: /home/foo/bar/tmp"
   ```

   Currently (because of `:` followed by space) you defined dictionaries, so for example in the first iteration `item` will have a value of `{ "APPHOME": "/home/foo/bar" }`, which will then always fail on the `when` condition.

---

Bonus problem:

- you defined a message in the form `"Variable '{{ item }}' is not defined"`;
- Ansible reports `Variable 'required_vars' is not defined`;
- the above is not an error, as you think ("*I get the following error*"), but a correct result of the `fail` module with the message you defined yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you. You have helped an absolute ansible newbie with your answer. But I have two more litte questions (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one value for 'with_items' I think it should look like this:

```
 with_items: "{{ required_vars }}"
```

On one line and with the brackets and quotation marks. Once you have more then one item, you can use the list like you did:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ one }}"
  - "{{ two }}"
```